# Recognizing the end of a sentence

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read a text file, and enter it into a vector string by string. I need it to stop at the end of each sentence, then pick out key words in the sentence. I understand how to find the key words, but not how to make it stop entering the strings at the end. I'm using a while loop to check each line, and I was considering using a series of if statements such as

```
if(std::vector<string>::iterator i == ".") i == "\0"
```

the code I have performing the vector-filling so far is:

```
std::string c;
ifstream infile;
infile.open("example.txt");
while(infile >> c){
    a.push_back(c);
}
```

Okay so i've comme up with a way to load each word of the text file into tokens, taking into account " " as the delimiter, and having a list of special case words:

```
    const int MAX_PER_LINE = 512;
    const int MAX_TOK = 20;
    const char* const DELIMETER = " -";
    const char* const SPECIAL ="!?.";
    const char* const ignore[]  = {"Mr.", "Ms.","Mrs.","sr.", "Ave.", "Rd."};
```

and then

```
             if(!file.good()){
         return 1;
     }
     //parsing algorithm paraphrased from cs.dvc.edu/HowTo_Parse.html
     while(!file.eof()){
     char line[MAX_PER_LINE];

     file.getline(line, MAX_PER_LINE);
     int n = 0;
     const char* token[MAX_TOK] = {};
     token[0] = strtok(line, DELIMETER);
     if(token[0]){
         for(n = 1; n < MAX_TOK; ++n){
             token[n] = strtok(0, DELIMETER);
             if(!token[n]) break;
         }
     }
     //for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
     for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
         cout << "Token[" << i << "] =" << token[i] << endl;
         cout << endl; 
     }
     }
```

now i'm looking for a what to put in an if statement, so that it checks each token for the special case, or if they follow a token with a special case, to load them into a new set tokens. I know the psuedo code for the most part, but I don't know what sort of syntax to put to that it would be like if(token[i] contains special case or token[i] doesn't have anything before it(for the first token) or is capitalized and follows a token with a special case to load it into a new token.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The period at the end of a sentence is usually attached to a word. It won't appear as its own string in the vector.

Comment: Doing this at all well is a non-trivial task. @DavidSchwartz has already given about as good an indication as is easily available, but it'll still go wrong at times, such as sentences containing abbreviations. For example, recognizing "Mr. Wong went to 119 S. Broad Street." as a single sentence instead of three isn't likely to be easy.

Comment: Hmm. I see your point. I'm not really sure how to go about this then.

Comment: I'd add that sentences also end with "!" and "?", and they include periods in the middle when people use periods to signal abbreviations like "e.g.". I'd suggest a more sophisticated approach.

Comment: Use a regular expression.

Comment: I've never used Regular Expressions before. I'll look into that.

Comment: I can't seem to figure out what i would do with a Regex, maybe i could run it in Char by char, and then end the line when ., ?, ;. or ! comes up

Comment: Check this out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_breaking

Comment: I think i understand. What i'm trying to do is read this sentence by sentence, then parse the sentence in Data pairs, the first and last words of the sentence

Answer (score 2):

Writing your own sentence delimiter is okay for small projects or project with no internationalization.
For advanced text based solutions on text boundaries, I would recommend ICU's [BreakIterator](http://userguide.icu-project.org/boundaryanalysis#TOC-Sentence-Boundary). Based on unicode.org standardization, they provide character, word, line-break and sentence boundaries. They have open source libraries in C++ (as well as in Java i think).
Refer [this page](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/) and it has link to download page of library.

This would avoid reinventing the wheel and avoid potential issues later on. Most leading publishing software products like QuarkXPress etc use this library.

EDIT:
I was trying to find a quick tutorial for ICU's BreakIterator usage on sentence boundaries but I found word boundaries example - (Sentence boundary calculation would be pretty much similar, probably need to just replace `createWordInstance` with `createSentenceInstance` in below)

```
void listWordBoundaries(const UnicodeString& s) {
    UErrorCode status = U_ZERO_ERROR;
    BreakIterator* bi = BreakIterator::createWordInstance(Locale::getUS(), status);


    bi->setText(s);
    int32_t p = bi->first();
    while (p != BreakIterator::DONE) {
        printf("Boundary at position %d\n", p);
        p = bi->next();
    }
    delete bi;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finding words that end in a period is pretty trivial, just check if `word.back() == '.'`. You'll also need to check `word.empty()` first, since [`back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/back) is undefined behavior if the string is empty. If your compiler doesn't support C++11, you can also do the longer way, with `word[word.size() - 1] == '.'`.

Here's a basic example that naïvely splits sentences using any word that ends with ".":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc == 1) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " [text to split]\n"
            << "Splits the input text into one sentence per line." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::vector<std::string> sentences;
    std::string current_sentence;
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        std::string word(argv[i]);
        current_sentence.append(word);
        current_sentence.push_back(' ');
        /* use word.back() == '.' for C++11 */
        if (!word.empty() && word[word.size() - 1] == '.') {
            sentences.push_back(current_sentence);
            current_sentence.clear();
        }
    }
    if (!current_sentence.empty()) {
        sentences.push_back(current_sentence);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sentences.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << sentences[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Run like:

```
$ g++ test.cpp
$ ./a.out This is a test. And a second sentence. So we meet again Mr. Bond.
This is a test. 
And a second sentence. 
So we meet again Mr. 
Bond.
```

Notice how it thinks "Mr." is the end of a sentence.

I'm not sure of a clever way of handling that, but one (fragile) option is to make a list of words that aren't the end of sentences, and then check if the word is in the list, like so:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

const std::string tmp[] = {
    "dr.",
    "mr.",
    "mrs.",
    "ms.",
    "rd.",
    "st."
};
const std::set<std::string> ABBREVIATIONS(tmp, tmp + sizeof(tmp) / sizeof(tmp[0]));

bool has_period(const std::string& word) {
    return !word.empty() && word[word.size() - 1] == '.';
}

bool is_abbreviation(std::string word) {
    /* Convert to lowercase, so we don't need to check every possible
     * variation of each word. Remove this (and update the set initialization)
     * if you don't care about handling poor grammar. */
    std::transform(word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), ::tolower);

    /* Check if the word is an abbreviation. */
    return ABBREVIATIONS.find(word) != ABBREVIATIONS.end();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc == 1) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " [text to split]\n"
            << "Splits the input text into one sentence per line." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::vector<std::string> sentences;
    std::string current_sentence;
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        std::string word(argv[i]);
        current_sentence.append(word);
        current_sentence.push_back(' ');
        if (has_period(word) && !is_abbreviation(word)) {
            sentences.push_back(current_sentence);
            current_sentence.clear();
        }
    }
    if (!current_sentence.empty()) {
        sentences.push_back(current_sentence);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sentences.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << sentences[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In C++11, you can make it more efficient by using `unordered_set`, and simpler by using `std::string::back` and the easier initialization (`std::set<std::string> PERIOD_WORDS = { "dr.", "mr.", "mrs." /*etc.*/ }`).

Running this version:

```
$ g++ test.cpp
$ ./a.out This is a test. And a second sentence. So we meet again Mr. Bond.
This is a test. 
And a second sentence. 
So we meet again Mr. Bond.
```

But of course, it still doesn't catch any case we didn't explicitly program in:

```
$ ./a.out Example Ave. is just north of here.
Example Ave. 
is just north of here.
```

And even if we added that in, it would be extremely difficult to detect cases like, "I live on Example Ave.", where the sentence ends with an abbreviation. I hope this is helpful as a start though.

---

EDIT: I just read the [sentence breaking Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_breaking) linked to in the comments, and it would be relatively easy to incorporate the rule:

> (c) If the next token is capitalized, then it ends a sentence.

Something like:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

const std::string tmp[] = {
    "ave.",
    "dr.",
    "mr.",
    "mrs.",
    "ms.",
    "rd.",
    "st."
};
const std::set<std::string> PERIOD_WORDS(tmp, tmp + sizeof(tmp) / sizeof(tmp[0]));

bool has_period(const std::string& word) {
    return !word.empty() && word[word.size() - 1] == '.';
}

bool is_abbreviation(std::string word) {
    /* Convert to lowercase, so we don't need to check every possible
     * variation of each word. Remove this (and update the set initialization)
     * if you don't care about handling poor grammar. */
    std::transform(word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), ::tolower);

    /* Check if the word is a word that ends with a period. */
    return PERIOD_WORDS.find(word) != PERIOD_WORDS.end();
}

bool is_capitalized(const std::string& word) {
    return !word.empty() && std::isupper(word[0]);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc == 1) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " [text to split]\n"
            << "Splits the input text into one sentence per line." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::vector<std::string> sentences;
    std::string current_sentence;
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        std::string word(argv[i]);
        std::string next_word(i + 1 < argc ? argv[i + 1] : "");
        current_sentence.append(word);
        current_sentence.push_back(' ');
        if (next_word.empty()
            || has_period(word)
            && (!is_abbreviation(word) || is_capitalized(next_word))) {
            sentences.push_back(current_sentence);
            current_sentence.clear();
        }
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sentences.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << sentences[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And then even cases like this work:

```
$ ./a.out Example Ave. is just north of here. I live on Example Ave. Test test test.
Example Ave. is just north of here. 
I live on Example Ave. 
Test test test.
```

But it still can't handle certain cases:

```
$ ./a.out Mr. Adams lives on Example Ave. Example Ave. is just north of here. I live on Example Ave. Test test test.
Mr. 
Adams lives on Example Ave. 
Example Ave. is just north of here. 
I live on Example Ave. 
Test test test.
```

Comment: How can you use Argv[i] like that?

Comment: 0.o how are you even loading that text into the program?

Comment: Could I use a loading method to load the text from file into argv[i]?

Comment: @user2325795 I'm using the program's arguments when running it on the console. For your purposes, you'll want to use [`std::ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) instead.